# Inner Join operations between two Elastic Types inside a single Index

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, nest, nosql

I have two Types such as Employees and Cities inside an Elastic Index,

The Type Employees  have document structure is like

```
[{
    "_index": "zase",
    "_type": "Employees",
    "_id": "100",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "sid": 100,
        "name": "San Andreas",
        "stageid": 0
    }
},
{
    "_index": "zase",
    "_type": "Employees",
    "_id": "101",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "sid": 101,
        "name": "Zack",
        "stageid": 0
    }
}]
```

The  Type Cities have  document  structure like as Follows,

```
[{
    "_index": "zase",
    "_type": "Cities",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "sid": 1,
        "name": "Virginia",
        "EmployeesID": [
            0:100,
            1:125,
            2:143
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "zase",
    "_type": "Cities",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "sid": 2,
        "name": "New Field",
        "EmployeesID": [
            0: 110
        ]
    }
}]
```

When Querying elastic search with  Cities name  'Virginia', I need to get the Employees information where  Cities.EmployeesID == Employees.sid,

Is this RDBMS Join operation across different Types possible in   Elastic Search?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is main usecase for your data retrieval, you may consider using [parent-child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/parent-child.html) relation as well.

Comment: Just know that if you have a use case where an employee can be in two different cities (working part time in one, part time in the other) then parent-child won't work

Answer (score 0):

JOIN queries are not supported in ES yet, though there's an [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6769) that is being discussed and a [pull request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/3278) that attempts to provide the feature, but work is currently stalled by some conflicts.

In the meantime, for your simple use case, you could probably use the [elasticsearch-sql](https://github.com/NLPchina/elasticsearch-sql) plugin in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: How can I use  elasticsearch-sql  in a dotnet client for Elastic ?  I am using NEST queries to retrieve data from elastic.

Comment: That plugin exposes an [endpoint called `/_sql`](https://github.com/NLPchina/elasticsearch-sql/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/plugin/nlpcn/RestSqlAction.java) which takes an `sql` parameter containing the SQL query you want to perform. You might try to hit that endpoint from NEST. See examples [here](https://github.com/NLPchina/elasticsearch-sql#basic-usage)